nginx ingress nodeport not working on kind
I'm trying to deploy a web service on to my local KinD cluster. Since I don't have an external facing IP, I choose NodePort instead of LB for my nginx ingress controller.
After I deployed my web service and before adding an ingress controller, I tried port forwarding to make sure my service is configured correctly using:
kubectl port-forward service/server-aac -n aac 9999:8080

and I was able to use Firefox to access localhost:9999 and see the sign in page.
Until this step, I'm very sure that my Deployment, Service and other stuffs are working correctly.
This is the service status:
% k get svc -n aac

NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
server-aac             ClusterIP   10.96.112.25   <none>        8080/TCP,8443/TCP    20h

Then I tried to add an ingress controller using the command:
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.3/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml

I also added the following entry in /etc/hosts:
<node-ip> aac.example.com

<node-ip> is from kubectl describe nodes | grep InternalIP 
After the nginx pods are ready and before setting up an ingress, I navigated to https://aac.example.com:31149 and sees a 404 in Firefox. This is expected because I haven't added any ingress rule.
This is the status of my ingress-controller:
%k get svc -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.96.100.0    <none>        80:31477/TCP,443:31149/TCP   159m
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.96.75.116   <none>        443/TCP                      159m


And then I added this ingress rule
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: aac-ingress
  namespace: aac
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: aac.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: server-aac
            port:
              number: 8080
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - aac.example.com
    secretName: aac-tls 

The cert and key in aac-tls are proven to be working when the web service is deployed either on GCP or AWS.
After adding the ingress rule to the cluster, I navigated to the same https://aac.example.com:31149 again which got immediately redirected to https://aac.example.com/login/login.html, then at this point Firefox is giving me

<In the URL box>: https://aac.example.com/login/login.htm

Unable to connect

An error occurred during a connection to aac.example.com.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.

Which tells me nginx did route the traffic but I don't know why my login page cannot show up. I did make sure my service can be reached at 8080 port using port-forwarding, and my ingress rule is pointing to this port. Also, it doesn't seem to be a certificate problem otherwise the browser would complain.
Can anyone shed some light on this, or let me know how to troubleshoot the problem between the ingress-controller and the service?

Ensure that example.com resolves correctly to Node IP. And you can verify this by running nslookup example.com and make sure that your local firewall rules allows traffic on the Nodeport you are using (which is 31149) and also check the NodePort is accessible from your local machine by running kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx.

And verify if there are any annotations in your ingress resource that might affect its behavior such as redirects or rewrites and since you mentioned port-forwarding works, verify that your service is accessible internally in the cluster via the specified port.

Did you have time to check my comment? It helped you to solve your problem? If not let me know, I am happy to assist you further.
